# React Date Picker, Range Picker

Tags: reactjs, daterangepicker

I'm working with React RangePicker and I have to clear out the default values once user clicks on the calendar. I have tried to use onOpenChange and set the state to null or empty string but it converts all of my calendar dates to Invalid date. Below is the code of my RangePicker.

````
            allowClear={false}
            disabledDate={disabledDate}
            onChange={(dates, dateString) => {
              dates && dates[0]
                ? setFromDate(dates[0].format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
                : setFromDate(null);
              dates && dates[1]
                ? setToDate(dates[1].format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
                : setToDate(null);
              console.log(dates, dateString)
            }}
            onOpenChange={(dates, dateString) => {
              setFromDate(moment(null))
              setToDate(moment(null))
              console.log(dates, dateString, dates[0], "ok")
            }}
            defaultValue={[
              moment(fromDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
              moment(toDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
            ]}
            ranges={{
              Today: [moment(), moment()],
              Yesterday: [
                moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
                moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
              ],
              'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'd'), moment()],
              'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment()],

              'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            }}
            value={[
              moment(fromDate,
                // ? fromDate : null,
                'DD-MM-YYYY'),
              moment(toDate,
                // ? toDate : null,
                'DD-MM-YYYY'),
            ]}
          />
        )}```
````

Comment: ```const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState(
    moment().subtract(7, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
  );
  const [toDate, setToDate] = useState(moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY'));```
state functions look like this.

Comment: Tried all the possible ways, onOpenChange, or in Onchange set the state to null but nothing is working.